# Eject a villager from a minecart to the left

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I found a really cool tutorial about how to build a villager trader hall. It  had a distribution system when villagers arrive by minecart, they are ejected by an activator rail and then they are pushed down to a "cell".

[image]

I didn't notice, but the design was intended for a setup where the villagers are ejected to the right (i.e. they arrive from the vantage point of the screenshot). I built my hall in a way that the villagers arrive from the opposite direction, so they have to be ejected to the left. When I try to ride the minecart myself, everything works as expected (I'm ejected to the left and I fall into a cell. However, villagers are ejected in front of the minecart (as far as I can tell). Is there a way to hotfix this problem? The only info that I found is that Minecraft searches for the most suitable block uppon ejecting someone from a minecart. But the ejection of the villagers is unexpected, and I don't understand why.

Comment: You could try placing glass above the rails.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the design entirely, but... Can't you just run the arrival track around to the other side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecart#Transportation) (emphasis mine):

> Players can exit the minecart by pressing sneak, however if there is only one block of headroom above the cart, the player takes 1♥ of suffocation damage. **When a minecart is exited, it searches for an adjacent or diagonal 2×2×3 area to put the player 1.5 blocks away from the cart**. If none are available, the player is deposited directly above the minecart. Consequently, the player falls inside the minecart.

While this does specify this for the "player", this is also true of the mobs, and in this case, the villagers.

So, what you can do (as [Fabian Röling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/360502/eject-a-villager-from-a-minecart-to-the-left#comment509541_360502) suggested) you can use [transparent blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Opacity#Types_of_transparent_blocks) to dictate the only "available" space to deposit the villager, to block off any other "valid" spaces (i.e. forcing the villager to be ejected to the left of the track).

> A player or mob riding in a minecart does not collide with or suffocate in any transparent blocks, but suffocates inside opaque blocks.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecart#Collision)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. It is interesting though that players riding a minecart don't need the restrictive glass blocks and always exit to the left, while villagers exit in a different way.